# Password save in Cache/Cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, passwords, storage

is there a way to save input type "password" in cache?

so every time you visit the page, password should not required.
but skip to the next step

```
<input type="password" name="lock_password" />
```

I tried with html5 LocalStorage but i fail.

Answer (score 0):

Older Browsers does not Support the HTML5 Web Storage

- Chrome: 4.0 or higher
- IE: 8.0 or higher
- FF: 3.5 or Higher
- Opera: 11.5 or higher
- Safari: 4.0 or higher

Saving your PW can be done like this:

**HTML**

```
<input id="testPassword" type="password" name="lock_password" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
// check if local storage is available
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // locale Storage supported

    // getting password from input
    var pw = document.getElementById("testPassword").value;

    // saving password in local storage
    localStorage.setItem("passwordKey", pw);

    // test if password is saved in local storage
    alert(localStorage.getItem("passwordKey"));
} else {
    // no local storage available
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/15q9hz48/)